# tableView reloadData not reloading data after deletion in documents directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, reloaddata

I have a problem where i cant seem to reload the data in my tableView.

What i am trying to do is populate my tableView with files in the documents directory with a csv extension (which i have done), then press a button which deletes all the displayed files and the updates the tableView.
The button when pressed deletes the files in the documents directory but does not reload the tableView with the updated content.

1. I have used breakpoints to confirm that reloadData is being run.
2. I have tried using removeAllObjects to clear my array before running
   reloadData using NSLog to confirm the array is empty, however this
   does not update the table.
3. I have tried setting the array to nil before running reloadData, this does not work either.
4. I have tried setting the data in the array to myArray = @[]; before
   running reloadData, this overwrites the array with blank data but
   does not update the table.
5. I have tried using this method without
   any success:

   ```
   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                   [self.tableView reloadData];
               });
   ```
6. I have checked my delegates for the tableView and they appear
   correct, (all other functionality in the tableView works including
   selecting/deselecting multiple items and deleting individual items
   and on each occasion the tableView updates).
7. I have also searched multiple different questions similar to mine and still have not found an answer.

Could someone please check my method below and tell me why the tableView is not reloading properly? i'm sure its something i have done wrong somwhere but i cant find it.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [filePathsArray count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }

    _docPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [_docPath objectAtIndex:0];
    _fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.csv'"];
    _csvFilesCell = [_fileList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];
    NSLog(@"Contents of directory: %@", _csvFilesCell);
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    cell.textLabel.text = [_csvFilesCell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(IBAction) deleteStoredData:(id)sender
{

    NSLog(@"Delete data button pressed");

    UIAlertController*alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Delete stored Data" message:@"Are you sure?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* OK = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Delete" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        NSFileManager  *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        // the preferred way to get the apps documents directory
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        // grab all the files in the documents dir
        NSArray *allFiles = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

        // filter the array for only csv files
        NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.csv'"];
        NSArray *csvFiles = [allFiles filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];

        // use fast enumeration to iterate the array
        for (NSString *csvFile in csvFiles) {

            NSLog(@"PATH %@ : FILE %@", documentsDirectory, csvFile);

            NSError *error = nil;

            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, csvFile]
                                                       error:&error];

            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            NSLog(@"OK button selected, all data deleted");

            [self updateDeleteButton];

            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


        }
    }];

    UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
        NSLog(@"Cancel button selected, no data deleted");
        [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
    [alert addAction:OK];
    [alert addAction:cancel];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: It'll not solve your issue, but you can move the call to `reloadData` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated` outside of the for loop. It is inefficient and can lead to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your code, I came up with the following solution, hope it helps you !!

```
_docPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [_docPath objectAtIndex:0];
_fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
NSPredicate *fltr = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.csv'"];
_csvFilesCell = [_fileList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltr];
NSLog(@"Contents of directory: %@", _csvFilesCell);
filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
```

The above code should be triggered at the click of delete button, not in the tableview's data-source method. After that you should reload your tableview and your **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method should be like :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = [_csvFilesCell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the above, unfortunatly the suggestion didnt work, it did however give me a few ideas for other possible solutions but they also didnt work. I assume that by removing the arrays from the **cellForRowAtIndexPath** you meant for them to be run elsewhere as by just removing them altogether it created an error in the table when the view loaded. I tried implementing them into the **viewDidLoad** which worked but also didnt fix the problem. Adding the code mentioned above to the **deleteStoredData** method caused the app to stop working when the button was pressed.